# Creating an html link to download and install a provisioning profile

Tags: html, ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I have a download link for an app (ad hoc, only to work on a few designated devices for testing). I have configured my plist file correctly, so the app itself downloads and installs without any issues. However, I think due to it being ad hoc, it does not install the certificate needed to run the app (I currently get the untrusted developer alert, and their is no certificate in general settings for me to trust).

So I tried to add a link for the provisioning profile on the same download page. Clicking on the link in the browser brings up an alert saying that Settings wants to show me a configuration profile. I click allow and it takes me to the Profile area in General settings, but there is nothing there.

How would I go about creating a simple link to download the profile onto the device? The code I used for the link is pretty straight forward.

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/myfolder/myProfile.mobileprovision">Profile</a>
```

Can anybody help? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be able to install an ad hoc app on devices through a web link, as long as the device ID is included in the bundled embedded.mobileprovision file included in the .ipa file.  I do not believe iOS allows you users to manually install profiles from Safari.  I think you would need to use a Mobile Device Management (MDM) solution to push profiles to devices.  However, you should not need to.  You should be able to embed the mobileprovision with the ipa.  I assume your app download link will only be shared with users on devices where you have added their device UDID to the profile?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So it turns out that the issue was when I was archiving the project from Xcode to an IPA file. I was using the default setting for the developer certificate that I should be signing my app with. It also had a dropdown list to select a second certificate (which as far as I can tell is still the same certificate). Selecting the second one seemed to sort the issue out, where as the default option for some reason did not include the certificate with my IPA file. Not sure why it worked this way, to be honest. App now installs and runs without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

> So I tried to add a link for the provisioning profile on the same download page.

You are not in a right direction. No one will ever do such download profile thing.

For Ad Hoc build, you have to add your desired devices to your `ad hoc provisioning profile`. I assume you did not do it so you can download the app but cannot install it.

So check your [developer certificate portal](http://developer.apple.com/certificates) and remember to re-generate your provisioning profile having these devices checked. And then build the app again with the new provisioning profile.